# .htaccess flat link

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, relative-path

I want to to use flat links like this:

```
http://somedomain.com/about-us
http://somedomain.com/products-list
http://somedomain.com/product/item
```

Thus I've used the mod_rewrite rules like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Za-z-]+)?$  /index.php?page=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Za-z-]+)/([0-9A-Za-z-]+)?$ /index.php?page=$1&value=$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The first two links are working fine. But whenever I visit the third type of links the images or the css or any js script that are linked as relative path eg. `<img src="images/image.jpg">` and `<a href="about-us">About Us</a>`.

The browser thinks it is in `http://somedomain.com/product/images/image.jpg` and `http://somedomain.com/product/about-us`.

The correct path should be `http://somedomain.com/images/image.jpg` and `http://somedomain.com/about-us`

And thus files with relative links are not working.

How to fix this issue? I don't want to use full path instead of relative for all linked files. Please suggest a way by doing some tweaks in the **.htaccess**

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping your slash:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Za-z-]+)\/([0-9A-Za-z-]+)?$ /index.php?page=$1&value=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks @Chris for your quick response.

But it's still not working. The browser is still thinking the the relative path is under the directory not in the root. **Relative links not working**.

As mentioned above its still linking as _http://somedomain.com/product/images/image.jpg_ NOT _http://somedomain.com/images/image.jpg_